# JSON output from MySQL works, but then white screen appears?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've used the below code to generate JSON from a MySQL table. It works great when I'm only generating 2 arrays, but for some reason when I try and generate 3 or 4 arrays, I get the "white screen of death". I thought it was happening because I needed to bump up my PHP Memory Limit, but I've done that and still get the same problem. See below:

**The code that works is:**

```
<?php
    //Create Database connection
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","user","dbpassword");
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select the Database
    mysql_select_db("dbname",$db);

    //Replace * in the query with the column names.
    $result = mysql_query("select * from customer", $db);  

    //Create an array
    $json_response = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['customerfname'] = $row['customerfname'];
        $row_array['customerlname'] = $row['customerlname'];

        //push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
    }
    echo json_encode($json_response);

    //Close the database connection
    fclose($db);

?>
```

**But when I attempt to call more values, this is where I get the blank screen:**

```
<?php
    //Create Database connection
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","user","dbpassword");
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select the Database
    mysql_select_db("dbname",$db);

    //Replace * in the query with the column names.
    $result = mysql_query("select * from customer", $db);  

    //Create an array
    $json_response = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['customerfname'] = $row['customerfname'];
        $row_array['customerlname'] = $row['customerlname'];
        $row_array['customeremail'] = $row['customeremail'];
        $row_array['customertel'] = $row['customertel'];

        //push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
    }

   var_dump($json_response);

   echo json_encode($json_response);



?>
```

**Update****

The error appears to be with my last line *(echo json_encode ($json_response);*

The following output is generated when I add *print_r($row)* before that last line.

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [customerfname] => First [customerlname] => Last [customeremail] => test@test.com [customerphone] => 000-000-0000
```

**Update 2**

Adding *var_dump($json_response);* before the *echo json_encode* line results in the blank screen.

Comment: You have `fclose($db);` at the end, that should be `mysql_close($db)`. You should not be using `mysql`, `mysqli` or `PDO` is a better choice.

Comment: @Lenny I changed fclose($db); to mysql_close($db) and it still doesn't work?

Comment: @Lenny Adding that shows me all of the data I want to see :) customerlname, customerfname, customertel, customeremail, etc.

Comment: @Lenny Ahhh wonderful. It appears as though the error is with this line: echo json_encode($json_response); (placing print_r...etc) before that line is where the error occurs. Any idea what I should replace that line with in order to output the JSON?

Comment: @Lenny Whoops! Sorry; see above :)

Comment: `print_r($json_response)` would be more useful. Here you're just printing out the contents of the last row.

Comment: @Lenny Version 5.426 :)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas; `var_dump($json_response)` before `echo json_encode(...)` and updated your question with that output instead and I can have a look if anything looks fishy with it. If you are running a local Apache server, restart it to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: You may want to try to add `print_r($row_array); print_r(json_encode($row_array));` just after the `array_push` line. Then check up up to which row it goes. I wouldn't be surprised if you had some type of accented char in the row it does not manage to encode.

Comment: @Lenny Added the var_dump($json_response) before the echo json_encode... and I still get the blank white screen :/ I don't understand how my code works when only pulling the first name and last name variable, but not when I try and pull any more than the first two? Lol

Comment: Post the var_dump in your question so people can see it :)

Comment: @Lenny See above; though no code is visible as a result, as I just get the "white screen of death/despair" lol.

Comment: Again, add `print_r($row_array); print_r(json_encode($row_array));` in the loop just after the `array_push` line. Then let us know how the output ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For future reference**: If someone else is visiting this question due to having a similar problem, the error with the blank page occurred since the query returned too many rows and `json_encode()` did not seem to be able to handle it.

---

Try the following, and share with us your result,

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //Create Database connection
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","user","dbpassword");
    if (!$db)
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("dbname",$db);

    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    $result = mysql_query("select `customerfname`, `customerlname`, `customeremail`, `customertel`  from customer", $db) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());  

    $json_response = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $json_response[] = $row; 
    }

   var_dump($json_response);

    /* If the var_dump works, you can try and uncomment this section
    if (function_exists('json_encode')) 
    {
        echo json_encode($json_response);
        echo "JSON Error: ".json_last_error();
    }
    else { echo "json_encode() is not supported"; }
    */
?>
```

Comment: So strange; same problem. This code works if I only query two of the variables (any two: customerfname and customerlname, or customerfname and customeremail); but using the above code as is (pulling more than two variables) gives me a blank white screen.

Comment: Correct; I've just edited your post and added the result. Again, including all variables gives me the white screen, but if I just call customerfname and customerlname, I get that result (see edit).

Comment: Wow, your array has 127481 rows?! That would probably have to do with the json_encode() failing. Limit your SQL query and you should be fine.

Comment: I know right? Craziness. Ahhh okay question: how do I limit my query?

Comment: It depend, what are you trying to do? Why do you want to output 130k items in JSON-format?

Comment: Just figured out how to limit my query. And the reason is because I'm using it to feed information to an iOS application I'm building; this JSON output manages a customer list. On that note, if I limit my query, I'm not able to see all of the customers; how should I go about that?

Comment: And ding ding ding; limiting my query works flawlessly. Apparently JSON doesn't like to pull that much data... Open to suggestions on that front though :)

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the data, presumably you don't need access to all 130k rows at once? You won't print 130k rows on a single page in your app? You should only extract the data you need each time, for example access to all names starting with `A`, or information about the user with name: `Adam Smith`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `flcose($db)` that is going to cause some trouble. remove that line.

flcose is used to close ressources such as writing to text files.

to close connection use `mysql_close()`:

```
mysql_close($db);
```

and also Your loop can be reduce to this:

```
//Create an array
$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    //push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response,$row);
}

//Close the database connection
mysql_close($db);

echo json_encode($json_response);
```

and I would probably echo the json after closing the connection but thats no biggie.

And I find `white screen of death` very funny `:D`

Comment: Lol. Tried this, still getting white screen of death O_O

Comment: It means there is some invalid character json_encode is failing to parse. check that record that is failing carefully it could even be some type of hyphene or quotes

Comment: That's so strange; if that's the case, why would it parse any two of the arrays, but not all of them at once?

Comment: `var_dump($json_response);` shows the correct values?

Comment: Yes, var_dump($json_response); shows me all values.